# Cookies not loading after getting the input from the user

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm learning to set and get cookies using javascript. Followed the tutorial by w3schools. It works well on the browser but doesn't fetch the cookies on my pc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
  const d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  let expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  let name = cname + "=";
  let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
  let user = getCookie("username");
  if (user != "") {
    alert("Welcome again " + user);
  } else {
     user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
     if (user != "" && user != null) {
       setCookie("username", user, 30);
     }
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="checkCookie()"></body>

</html>
```

I tried repeating the tutorial again but the results were same. I want the cookies displayed on my browser after getting the input

Answer (score 0):

Simply run your .html page on IIS you will get your result

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).